# highchart editor library event listening

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-editor

I'm having trouble for binding event function to highchart editor library.

I want to perform action when editor library perform its action. For example,
for hook 'ImportCSV', 'Change' and 'ChartChange' i want to attach function with editor library. 
I'm trying to do so by this code:

```
let edit = highed.Editor(document.body)

edit.on('ImportCSV', function () {
//Do something with the modified chart here.
console.log('ImportCSV')
})
```

and by this too

```
let edit = highed.Editor(document.body, {
  on: {
    'Change': function(){
                        console.log('Change')
              },
    'ChartChange': function(){
                        console.log('ChartChange')
              },
     'ImportCSV': function(){
                        console.log('ImportCSV')
              }
   }
})
```

But both method is not working for me.
MY question is that whats the right way to perform particular task, when certain hook is fired.

ref: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-editor/wiki/Editor-API

Answer (score 1):

You can use Editor events like that:

```
highed.ready(function() {
  var Editor = highed.Editor(document.body, {
    defaultChartOptions: {
      title: {
        text: 'Cool Chart!'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'My Cool Chart!'
      },
      data: {
        csv: "\"row\";\"val\"\n\"2013-01-01\";24\n\"2014-01-01\";76\n\"2015-01-01\";23"
      }
    },
    features: 'import export templates customize'
  });

  Editor.chart.on('ChartChange', function(data) {
    console.log('Chart changed! -> ', data);
  });
});
```

However, as you can read in the docs there are no such events like ImportCSV or Change.